# How can you, with bash, check all files in a directory to see which ones (if any) something was written to?

Tags: bash, grep

I ran a script which acts on multiple "people", and creates output and error files for each. let's say something like this:

```bash
output_alice.txt
error_alice.txt
output_bob.txt
error_bob.txt
.
.
.
```

I want a command that will scan all the error files (`error_<name>.txt`) and echo the ones that have had something written to them (vs being empty), as a quick way to identify which "people" the script exited with an error for. Is there an easy way to do this? I know how to use grep to do this for a string, e.g. `grep -r <substring> .`, but not how to check if there is anything at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that bash is not a *terminal*, it's one of many *shells*, which are interpreters for some kinds of programming languages specialised in running commands. Like most applications it can work with its input/output connected to a terminal device or any other type of file.

To `l`ist the files named `error_anything.txt` in the current working directory that contain at least one line, in the language of bash and most other Unix shells, you can do:

```
grep -l '^' error_*.txt
```

Where `^` is a regular expression that matches at the start of the subject, *subject* being each line in the file for `grep`.

For those with at least one non-empty text line:

```
grep -l . error_*.txt
```

Where `.` matches any single character. Beware for files encoded in a charmap other than that of the locale, it could fail to match non-empty lines if their contents cannot be decoded as text.

Also note that not all `grep` implementations will report files with only one unterminated line (one missing the line delimiter like in the output of `printf invalid-text-as-missing-the-last-newline`).

Another approach is to look for files that contain at least one byte:

```
find -L . ! -name . -prune -name 'error_*.txt' -type f -size +0c
```

Which also has the benefit of ignoring files that are not of type *regular* (such as directories, sockets...)

Or with the zsh shell:

```
print -rC1 -- error_*.txt(N-.L+0)
```

Where `-` acts like `-L` so that for symlinks, the size and type of their targets be considered, `.` is the equivalent of `-type f` and `L+0` of `-size +0c` (and `N` for `N`ullglob so as not to report an error if there's no matching file).

That has the benefit of not including the `./` prefix and of working even if the user name cannot be decoded as text in the locale and of giving you a (lexically by default) sorted list.

That one you can extend to only print the user name (the part of the `r`oot name of the file after the first `_`) with:

```
{}{ print -rC1 -- ${@#*_}; } error_*.txt(N-.L+0:r)
```

To list `error` files that have been modified since you ran a command, you can use the `-newer` predicate of `find` and compare with a file that have been `touch`ed just before running your command:

```
touch .before
my-command-that-may-write-to-error-files
find -L . ! -name . -prune -name 'error_*.txt' -type f -size +0c -newer .before
```

In zsh, you can replace the `find` command with:

```
print -rC1 -- error_*.txt(N-.L+0e['[[ $REPLY -nt .before ]]'])
```

With some `find` implementations, you can replace `! -name . -prune` with `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` though `-maxdepth 1` would also work here as the file at depth 0 (`.`) doesn't match the other criteria (it matches neither `-name 'error_*.txt'` nor `-type f`) anyway.

With the GNU implementation of `date` and `find` (that's also the `find` implementation that introduced the `-maxdepth` predicate), you can avoid having to create that `.before` file by doing:

```
before=$(date +'@%s.%N')
my-command-that-may-write-to-error-files
find -L . -maxdepth 1 -name 'error_*.txt' -type f -size +0c -newermt "$before"
```

With `zsh`, you can replace the `before=$(date +'@%s.%N')` with `print -Pv before '@%D{%s.%N}'` or `before=${(%):-@%{%s.%N}D}` or `before=@$EPOCHREALTIME` (after `zmodload zsh/datetime`); you could again avoid the call to `find` by using *glob qualifiers*, and even the temporary variable by using an anonymous function again, but that becomes significantly involved:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
zmodload zsh/datetime
() {
  my-command-that-may-write-to-error-files
  print -rC1 error_*.txt(N-.L+0e['
    stat -F %s.%N -A2 +mtime -- $REPLY && (( $2 > $1 )) '])
} $EPOCHREALTIME
```

Beware though that on Linux at least, even though the system and filesystems support nanosecond precision, granularity is much less. You can even find that modification time is set upon modification to some value that predates the initial call to `date` or reference to `$EPOCHREALTIME` so those approaches may not work for commands that take less than a centisecond to run. Dropping `N`anoseconds and  replacing `>` with `>=` or `-newer` with `! -older` (if your `find` implementation supports it which is unlikely) may be a better approach.

Comment: thank you! In your answer you mention "Note that some grep implementations will also report files that have a non-line." What is a non-line?

Comment: @abra see edit. Lines are sequences of 0 or more characters delimited by a newline characters and that don't have a length greater  than the LINE_MAX limit in byte. So bytes that don't form characters, or overlong lines, or the bytes if any after the last newline character in the file would form non-lines.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I marked your answer as accepted. The command "grep -l . error_*.txt" is what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: What a wonderful tutorial for what could have been a brief answer. A lot of fixes for potential issues to watch out for.

Answer (score 10):

GNU `find` offers the non-POSIX option to list empty files, simply negate that test:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -name 'error_*.txt' ! -empty
```

For **not** searching in subdirectories add `-maxdepth 1` after the path.

In POSIX `find` checking for a file size of `0` would work:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -name 'error_*.txt' ! -size 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Just grep for `.`, which means any character. Empty files have no characters, so searching for `.` will show non-empty files. For example:

```
$ touch empty1 empty2 empty3
$ echo "not empty!" > non_empty
$ ls -l 
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon  0 Aug 11 13:13 empty1
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon  0 Aug 11 13:13 empty2
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon  0 Aug 11 13:13 empty3
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 11 Aug 11 13:13 non_empty
```

Now, we grep:

```
$ grep -- . ./*
non_empty:not empty!
```

And, to get names only:

```
$ grep -l -- . ./*
non_empty
```

Note that `grep .` will not find a file that has nothing empty line(s) (one or more `\n` characters). For that, you should use `grep '^'` as suggested in [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753808/22222).

Answer (score 1):

Another one-line method for searching for non-empty files.

```
$ for f in `ls error_*.txt`; do [ -s "${f}" ] && echo ${f} ; done
```

Where

-s **FILE** ,  True if file exists and is not empty.

Explanation

Loop through list of all files in current directory, that matches error_*.txt . Function checks "-s" if file exists and contains something, if so then display the file name.

Comment: You should never do ``for `f in `ls error_*.txt` ``. Just use `for f in error_*.txt` directly.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @muru So I'm curious, what is the background on why no quote character ?

Comment: @Iain4D see the last link from Stéphane's comment above.

Comment: @muru Hmm.. thanks for the link reference.  However looks like it is for double-quotes. One of the comments there linked to the [always use quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) so I wonder if that implies more applicable to  `for` loops ?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the links and background on printf vs echo preferences. I read through the explanation and it makes total sense. I got it.  Then got to the end of one of the comments . . . and then it mentioned `for simple basic cases where $var is known text ,  echo ${var} would suffice for your needs". (facepalm)

Comment: After some testing with bash on CentOS Stream 9 (RH based) and Ubuntu 22.04 versions of bash.  I also discovered that `echo "-n" ` will result in parameter of no new-line character.  However, extra space added (before or after) prints as expected, `echo " -n"` or `echo "-n " .

On the other hand, `echo "\t"` is treated as text unless you make it `echo -e "\t"`then special characters are processed and in this case becomes a TAB character.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed only. Like an alternative for the `grep` command:

```bash
sed -sn 1F error_*.txt
```

! I have not met the command `F` in the man pages, but it works. In particular, I insert file names in the first line of nonempty files `sed -i 1F *`